# Custom button to iOS print panel

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, button, printing

I was wondering if it's possible to add a custom button to the print panel (UIPrintInteractionController) in an iOS app and if so how to go about doing that. Thanks.

Comment: A custom button to do what? It's a print interaction controller? You can perform custom printing and invoke it via any button you want. Is that what you are talking about?